# JPA could not locate parameter while working with Stored procedure using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jpa, stored-procedures, entitymanager

Any efforts in following problem would be highly appreciable.
I am trying to invoke stored procedure using @NamedStoredProcedureQueries

Here is the code snippet of my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tx_oppertunity")

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ //
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "oppertunity.pastOppertunities", procedureName = "pastOppertunities",resultSetMappings="myMapping")})

@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
            name = "myMapping",
            classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = DataHolder.class, columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "oppertunityid") }))
    })


public class Oppertunity {

    /** The oppertunity id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GEN_TX_OPPERTUNITY_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "GEN_TX_OPPERTUNITY_SEQ", sequenceName = "tx_oppertunity_seq")
    @Column(name = "oppertunity_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long oppertunity_id;

  // other fields to follow
}
```

My stored procedure is written in postgres and looks like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pastOppertunities()
  RETURNS TABLE(oppertunityid integer) AS
$BODY$  
    BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY select cast((opp.oppertunity_id) as integer)  from tx_oppertunity opp where (opp.end_date)< (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days'); 
     END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Since I am using SQL Resultset mapping to map my result from stored procedure I have defined target class to hold those values as DataHolder.class which looks like this.

```
public class DataHolder implements Serializable{

    private Integer oppertunityid;

    /**
     * @return the oppertunityid
     */
    public Integer getOppertunityid() {
        return oppertunityid;
    }

    /**
     * @param oppertunityid the oppertunityid to set
     */
    public void setOppertunityid(Integer oppertunityid) {
        this.oppertunityid = oppertunityid;
    }

    public DataHolder(Integer oppertunityid) {

        this.oppertunityid = oppertunityid;
    }

}
```

However If I try to run the procedure using, JPA repository

```
@Procedure(name = "oppertunity.pastOppertunities")
public List<DataHolder> findPastOppertunities();
```

It gives me following exception,

```
11:51:07.200 [http-nio-8000-exec-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate parameter registered using that position [1]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate parameter registered using that position [1]] with root cause
org.hibernate.procedure.NoSuchParameterException: Could not locate parameter registered using that position [1]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getParameterRegistration(ProcedureCallImpl.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.getOutputParameterValue(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.getOutputParameterValue(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.extractOutputValue(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:120) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:298) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:99) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I am not sure what exactly I am missing here all parameters are specified correctly in @SQLREsultSetMapping and I added explicit typecast in procedure to compulsory return Integer value.

There was some post which was suggesting to use Entity manager to call stored procedure, after a long fight I made call using entity manager and it worked like a charm

```
public List<DataHolder> findPastOppertunities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StoredProcedureQuery spq = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("pastOppertunities");
            List<DataHolder> resultList = spq.getResultList();
            return resultList;
        //return oppRepo.findPastOppertunities();

    }
```

However I want to understand if its bug with JPA repositories, Why JPA is not able to map result from strored procedure using @SqlResultSetMapping.

Thanks,
Dipesh